# How to get character one by one from a string using string tokenizer in java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a complex string and I just need to get each and every char in this string one by one.
Here what I did, but at one place I am getting both **/(** I know what because there is a no delimiter between them. How can I overcome this?

Hear is my string : `3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 )`

My code:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(mathExpression , "+-x/()");
StringTokenizer tokenizer2 = new StringTokenizer(mathExpression , "123456789");

while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {           
  System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());            
}

while (tokenizer2.hasMoreElements()) {              
  System.out.println(tokenizer2.nextToken());               
}
```

Output :

```
3
4
2
1
5
+
x
/(
-
)
```

Comment: What is the value for mathExpression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An instance of StringTokenizer behaves in one of two ways, depending
> on whether it was created with the returnDelims flag having the value
> true or false:
>
> •If the flag is false, delimiter characters serve to separate tokens.
> A token is a maximal sequence of consecutive characters that are not
> delimiters.
>
> •If the flag is true, delimiter characters are themselves
> considered to be tokens. A token is thus either one delimiter
> character, or a maximal sequence of consecutive characters that are
> not delimiters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

```
 StringTokenizer(mathExpression , "+-x/()", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. You can just use [`String#getChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29) or [`String#toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

Comment: It's String#toCharArray().

Comment: I can not use char array because I will destroy my double values like i.e 67.4

Comment: @CodeSac Your question was about getting the characters of a string: "(...)I just need to get each and every char in this string one by one(...)"! That's exactly what the code in our answers do!

Comment: @CodeSac Sorry, your question is **"I just need to get each and every char in this string one by one"**, I don't see what relevance what the chars actually are has.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a `StringTokenizer`? Just iterate the `String`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    char c = myString.charAt(i);
    // do something with c
}
```

If you're not directly interested in single chars but want to have all of them at once, you can also request a `char[]` from the string:

```
char[] chars = myString.toCharArray();
```

(Note that this will return a copy of the `String`-internal char array, so if you just want to process single chars, the first method might be less memory- and performance-intensive).

Comment: @m0skit0 Maybe. But usually you want to do something with the single chars, so in the end you will have to iterate. So why not directly?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, we don't know what the OP wants to do with the array actually.